# provide limit for SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, share

I have made my app shareable using this code:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.s5.selfiemonkey1.activity.SharingImagesActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem is that I am able to share one or more images, but I want to provide a limit for images.

This means that when user selects two or more images to share in a gallery, the app icon should become hidden from the share list. However, if a user only select one or less, then the app icon should be visible in the share list.

Comment: If your app accepts only one item, remove `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>` line. You need to add this line only if your app can process more than one shared items.

Comment: ok...but i want to allow for two images only means one or two only

Comment: is any way to allow limit for shared item .if user choose more then two images my app icon should be hidden from share list

Comment: No. It's either one or many. You cannot define a specific number. What you can do is, when the user comes to your app with more than 2 images, you can tell that the app cannot accept more than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app accepts only one item, remove: 
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>` line. You need to add this line only if your app can process more than one shared items